# How should I present my telephone number?

Tags: numbers

How should I write my mobile telephone number in an email?

I want to send something like

> Hi,
>
> Following is my mobile number 0000 000 000
>
> Thanks

or

> Hi,
>
> My mobile number is 000 000 0000
>
> Please feel free to call me whenever needed.
>
> Thanks

Should I use spaces in the number? Or write it in one single block 0000000000? Or some other way?

Comment: "Following is my mobile number" is not standard English. Do not use it. You could say "Here is my mobile number:" instead. As for tone, that's less related to English and more related to the nature of the relationship. Often, you don't write your boss using the same tone as writing your best friend.

Comment: It looks like a specific source of concern has clearly been identified, so I don't think this question should be closed as proofreading.

Comment: The formatting of phone numbers commonly used varies by locale, but the common ones are "(000)000-0000" and "000-000-0000". Don't use a single block.

Answer (score 3):

This varies by region.

In the US, the common way to write a telephone number is with the telephone area code (for example "206" is "Seattle") in brackets, and with a hyphen after the first triple:

> My telephone number is (206) 123-4567

or alternatively:

> My telephone number is 206-123-4567

In the United Kingdom, the common way is to write a landline telephone number with a space after the area code (or the area code in brackets) and an additional space breaking up any seven remaining digits into a 3-4 tuple or eight remaining digits into a 4-4 tuple:

> My telephone number is (01244) 123 4567
>
> My telephone number is 01244 123 4567
>
> My telephone number is 020 7738 1033

Mobile telephone numbers in the UK tend to be written "flat". In the US there is no distinction between mobile telephone numbers and landline ones, so the landline convention holds.

> My telephone number is 07771234567

When writing international telephone numbers in the US, the format is usually thus:

> My telephone number is +1 (206) 123-4567

In the UK when writing international telephone numbers, the "0" digit at the start of the area code is dropped for international dial-ins, so the leading zero is bracketted:

> My telephone number is +44 (0)7771234567
>
> My telephone number is +44 (0)20 7738 1033

However, if in doubt, just write the number direct without spaces or brackets. Be sure to include the international prefix if your telephone number is not from the same country as the person you are talking to. For instance, if you are currently living in the Netherlands and you are applying for a job in the United States, be sure to include the international dialing prefix for the Netherlands in your telephone number so that the person you are talking to can phone you.

Comment: In the U.S., those first three digits are almost always called the *area code*, not the *prefix*.  In fact, if you said *prefix*, I'd assume you meant the next three digits (the NXX or *central office code*).

Comment: @snailboat: It's called the area-code in the UK as well. The prefix is the international bit with the +44/+1 at the start. I'll edit to make it more clear.

Comment: This does a good job describing formal ways to write phone numbers, but it's worth mentioning how this is morphing some, by using dots (periods) to try an look more modern (or perhaps because it's an easier separator on number pads). Thus, we might see the date 11.12.13 (coming later this year), or the phone number 555.867.5309. This format is becoming more and more acceptable, particularly on webpages and in print ads. See [here](http://www.fedex.com/us/customersupport/call/phonemenu.html) and [here](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=225) for examples.

Comment: @Matt Your answer is good and clear (and I upvoted it).  But just to be clear, your comment is not accurate regarding US usage: bare *prefix* doesn't mean the international bit in the US.  It's understood to mean the [telephone prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_prefix) (the NXX or *central office code*).

Comment: @snailboat: Huh. Learn something new every day. I don't think *international dialing prefix / international prefix* would be misunderstood though, so I'm not sure I need to change the answer. If you disagree, please feel free to edit my answer directly though.